# How do I Implement CopyMemory(C++) in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to rewrite the following code from C++ to C# but cannot make the same output, could anyone here give me some idea? Thanks a lot!

```cpp
AnsiString asImg = "0001";
AnsiString asLen;
asLen.SetLength(4);
long lnLen = asImg.Length();
CopyMemory(asLen.c_str(), &lnLen, sizeof(long));
```

Comment: This code is not translatable to C# as this code performs manual memory operations that are unnecessary in .NET.

Comment: One of C#'s claims to safety is preventing you from doing things like this.

Comment: You can not convert this code to C#, since C# has no `AnsiString` class. And no string class in general that holds 8 bit code points. Depending on what you're actually trying to do, the best way to achieve it could look very different. So maybe you should elaborate some futher.

Comment: @Paul: No reason you can't use `byte[]` though.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: Yes, you could. Only a `byte[]` is not a string. And we cannot know if a `byte[]` is what he needs. E.g. it's also possible that he needs a `System.String` with the byte sequence converted to Unicode using the system codepage. Or a zillion other things that I cannot think of right now. Too much uncertainty for me to spend time on writing an answer. And of course answering bad/incomplete questions with good answers only leads to more bad/incomplete questions.

Comment: That code exhibits undefined behavior. You cannot write to `c_str()`.

Answer (score -1):

The "morally equivalent" code to that you show above would be something like:

```
string asImg = "0001";
string asLen = asImg;
```

If you want something that's more similar in terms of memory access pattern, you'd need to do something like:

```
byte[] asImg = new[] {(byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'1'};
byte[] asLen = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(asImg, asLen, 4);
```

(but this later version is really strange and not what a C# programmer should write)

If you want to interpret the byte string 0001b as an integer, you can use `BitConverter`:

```
byte[] asImg = new[] {(byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'1'};
// "int" is probably the same size as "long" in your C example
int asLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(asImg, 0);
```